# nginx issue : reload: Name "com.ubuntu.Upstart" does not exist

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-16.04

restarting nginx using `sudo service nginx restart` is ok .but reloading it using `service nginx reload` get this error on Ubuntu 16.04:

> reload: Name "com.ubuntu.Upstart" does not exist

Answer (score 7):

Ubuntu 16.04 has poor error handling for this case. The error

```
Name "com.ubuntu.Upstart" does not exist
```

usually just means "Access Denied". Are you sure you had `sudo` there, too?

Comment: Why can't it just say so ?

Comment: I'd guess that's just poor quality control. Pretty much all upstart related stuff seems to be done with great hurry.